# How to write a SQL query that subtracts INNER JOIN results from LEFT JOIN results?

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

ere's an example: I want to see how good my marketing efforts are working for a product I'm trying to sell in a store. For instance, I want to know how many people bought my product within a month after they received a coupon for it in their email on 12/1/2014, compared to how many people bought my product in that same time period without ever receiving a coupon.
Here's a sample of my Customer table:

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER        PURCHASE_DATE
---------------        -------------
1                      2014-12-02
2                      2014-12-05 
3                      2014-12-05 
4                      2014-12-10 
5                      2014-12-21
```

Here's a sample of my Email table

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER        EMAIL_ADDR         SEND_DATE
---------------        ------------       ----------
1                      john@abc.com       2014-12-01
3                      mary@xyz.com       2014-12-01
5                      beth@def.com       2014-12-01
```

I have a pretty good idea how to determine who bought the product with the coupon: I use an inner join on the two tables. But in order to determine who bought the product anyway, even though they didn't have a coupon for whatever reason (they don't have email, they're part of a control group, etc.), I *think* I need to use a left join to get a result set, and then subtract the results of the inner join from my first result set. Alas, that is where I am stuck. In the example above, Customers 2 and 5 bought the product even though they never received a coupon, but I cannot figure out how to write a query to return that data. 
I am using IBM's Netezza DB. Thank you!!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's just an opinion, but I really wish people would use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` and forget this `IN (subquery)` syntax entirely!!!

Comment: You know what - I agree :)

Comment: @JasonBodak The purchase dates in your example are all *before* the email send dates. Did you mean to make the purchase dates after `2014-12-05` but before `2014-12-27`?

Comment: Or perhaps you meant for the `Send_Date` to be all the same `2014-12-01` and the `Purchase_Date` to be different for each customer?

Comment: Sorry, ErikE, and thanks for the catch. I fixed the email SEND_DATEs and the PURCHASE_DATEs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Left Outer Join` with `NULL` check

```
SELECT C.*
FROM   customer C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN email e
                    ON C.customer_Number = E.customer_Number
WHERE  E.customer_Number IS NULL
```

Or use `Not Exists`

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer C
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   email e
                   WHERE  c.customer_number = e.customer_number)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Both of your solutions worked flawlessly. You are my new hero!

Answer (score 0):

```
select from customers c left outer join email e
on c.customer_number = e.customer_number
    where e.customer_number is null
        or C.purchase_date < e.send_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   C.*,
   PurchasedWithin30DaysOfEmailedCoupon =   
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM
            Email E
         WHERE
            C.CustomerID = E.CustomerID
            AND C.Purchase_Date <= E.Send_Date
            AND E.Send_Date < DateAdd(day, 30, C.Purchase_Date)
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
   Customer C
WHERE
   C.PurchaseDate IS NOT NULL
;
```

Please forgive me for not knowing the correct syntax for adding 30 days to a date in your DBMS--I'm sure that will be a simple fix for you.

You can then simply group by the `PurchasedWithin30DaysOfEmailedCoupon` value and get your count.